# Printing a diagonal matrix by using Eigen library

Tags: c++, eigen3

I want to create a diaonal matrix by using the Eigen library, but I'm having a problem.

When I run the following code,

```
Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<float, 2> diagonalMatrix1(2,2);
std::cout << "Diagonal Matrix:\n" << diagonalMatrix1 << endl;
```

I get the following error.

```
error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, std::basic_ostream<char>&>’
```

I'm unable to print the diagonal matrix. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: fwiw, the fragment of the error message you posted is almost useless. It only tells us that there is SFINAE being used somewhere, but where and due to what condition it failed is only contained in the complete error message.

Answer (score 3):

You can cast it to a printable type and then print it e.g.:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<float, 2> matrix(2,2);

    std::cout << "matrix:\n" << matrix.toDenseMatrix() << std::endl;
}
```

```
matrix: 
2 0
0 2
```